# Mouse scrolling in vim scrolls terminal window

Tags: vim

I am just getting started using Vim and came across `:set mouse=a` which I've found really useful for navigating a file, however for some reason when I try and scroll now it scrolls the whole terminal window and not just the vim window.

[image]

Then I scroll up and can see the terminal outside Vim

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried resetting `mouse=` and exiting and re entering vim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I had accidentally disabled `Allow Mouse Reporting` in error.

Checking `Menu > View > Allow Mouse Reporting` or `Cmd + R` has fixed it!

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I'm coming back to this question every now and then

Answer (score 2):

I think the cheap answer to your question is that you should be navigating through files in vim using motion commands, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>, etc. It might seem slow at first, but it really becomes more natural down the line.

That said, if you are on Mac and using Terminal, you might need to hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> to temporarily disable mouse support. (Check this out for reference: [OS X Terminal Mouse Support](https://superuser.com/a/985865)

Also, you can always try MacVim, which supports mouse scrolling out of the box.

If neither of those solutions work for you, some more information would be helpful for troubleshooting, e.g., your operating system, recent changes to your vimrc, etc.

Comment: Yeah I know I should be, I just feel that as soon as I start doing that it all just becomes too real !!

Comment: Being one who is loathe to leave the keyboard, on the other hand if you already have your hand on the mouse then it's faster/more natural to just move your mouse to the other window and scroll. Especially if you're in Mac/Linux where the focus follows the mouse.